# System.Device.Location.Portable 1.0.0 package may not be fully compatible with your project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am developing a web application using asp.net core 2.0 and installed a package named System.Device.Location.Portable 1.0.0 using nuget. Under dependencies I see this warning:

http://prntscr.com/kmbazb

```
warning NU1701: Package 'System.Device.Location.Portable 1.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

I used [nuget package explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) and here are the details of package.

http://prntscr.com/kmbddc

How to fix this or any alternate package for asp.net core?

Comment: you can disable this warning in your project : Properties -> Build -> Suppress warnings

Comment: I don't want to suppress it. I want to resolve it. Any alternate of using System.Device.Location.Portable?